# Is using __add__ in Python on an int a bad idea?

Tags: python

I'm looking to increment a value by one and Python does not have the ++ operator. Consider the following example:

```
# In a method called calculate(self, basecost, othertaxes=None)
# Returns the value of the tax (self) applied to basecost in relation to previous taxes
i = -1
basecost += sum((tax.calculate(basecost, othertaxes[:i.__add__(1)]) for tax in othertaxes))
```

Is the use of __add__ in this example a bad idea? Is there a better way to write this statement?

Cheers - D

---

UPDATE

I have changed the answer because the for ... in ...: v += calc solution is much faster than the sum() method. 6 seconds faster over 10000 iterations given my setup but the performance difference is there. Bellow is my test setup:

```
class Tax(object):
    def __init__(self, rate):
        self.rate = rate

def calculate_inline(self, cost, other=[]):
    cost += sum((o.calculate(cost, other[:i]) for i, o in enumerate(other)))
    return cost * self.rate

def calculate_forloop(self, cost, other=[]):
    for i, o in enumerate(other):
        cost += o.calculate(cost, other[:i])
    return cost * self.rate

def test():
    tax1 = Tax(0.1)
    tax2 = Tax(0.2)
    tax3 = Tax(0.3)
    Tax.calculate =  calculate_inline # or calculate_forloop
    tax1.calculate(100.0, [tax2, tax3]) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
    t = Timer('test()', 'from __main__ import test; gc.enable()')
    print t.timeit()
```

With `Tax.calculate = calculate_inline`, the problem took 16.9 seconds, with `calculate_forloop`, it took 10.4 seconds.

Comment: Does Python have an addition operator `+` ?

Comment: Yes, but no increment operator (e.g. i++ or ++i). In the line, I need i to increment by one and returned.

Comment: >>> i = 0
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a[:i += 1]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a[:i += 1]
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: why not just `othertaxes[:i+1]`?

Comment: @Chris, i does not increment when you do i + 1

Comment: Ugly as that looks, does `__add__` actually work?

Comment: @Robert, yeah. It would be a neat solution if it were not for the magic method.

Comment: I've seen that horrendous double-underscore thing in Python code before.  If it's only ugly you're worried about, I wouldn't lose any sleep over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading that right:

```
for i,tax in enumerate(othertaxes):
    basecost += tax.calculate(basecost,othertaxes[:i])
```

Comment: Equally good and probably more legible answer. But I do like the one-line approach. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9):

Seems to be this:

```
basecost += sum((tax.calculate(basecost, othertaxes[:i]) 
                      for i,tax in enumerate(othertaxes))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, integers  are not mutable (neither are floats, booleans or strings).

You cannot change the value of i unless you write i += 1. i.**add**(1) does not change the value of i, it just returns a new integer which equals (i+1).

Answer (score 0):

You would normally do a `lambda x: x+1` instead of using `__add__`